# Настройка .htaccess для приведения к единому варианту обращения к сайту

Tags: .htaccess, настройка

Нужна помощь с .htaccess

Цель такая:

Нужно сделать так, чтобы любой вариант обращения к сайту, приводился к виду: https://site.com

То есть:

Если пользователь вбивает в адресной строке (или переходит откуда то по ссылке):

http://site.com

http://www.site.com

https://www.site.com

[www.site.com](http://www.site.com)

site.com

То он в любом случае попадает на сайт: https://site.com

Как это можно реализовать в файле .htaccess ?

Comment: Пока сидел, разобрался, как сделать принудительное перенаправление на https://
Осталось понять, что написать в .htaccess, чтобы убрать www

Comment: Проблема решена